# How do I Convert Integer value to Binary value as a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Not sure if I worded the title correctly, so my apologies.

I want to simply convert an integer to strings that hold the binary representation of that integer.

**Example**:
116 would convert to "1110100"

Is there anything built into .Net or will I need to write a small parsing algorithm?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This will do it:

```
// bin = "1110100"
var bin = Convert.ToString(116, 2)
```

The second parameter specifies which base to convert to.

Comment: I figured .Net had some type of method but couldn't find anything before your answer. Thanks so much!